# ASN1 parsing with swift

Tags: swift, openssl, in-app-purchase, asn.1

I think I get the basic idea behind ASN.1 parsing. Walk the bytes, interpret them and do something useful with them. Alas I am stuck on the implementation.

Apple has no sample code (that I could find), probably for security reasons. OpenSSL is not very well documented, so I can only guess at what the functions actually do. The only [sample code in swift](http://swiftrien.blogspot.be/2015/05/osx-receipt-validation-in-swift-part-1.html) I did find doesn't handle case 17 (the in-app purchases), which is the one thing I am interested in.

I tried figuring out where in the data stream the pointer is located, but I always get the same nonsensical result of 49.

```
    let receiptContents = NSData(contentsOfURL: receiptLocation)!

    let receiptBIO = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem())
    BIO_write(receiptBIO, receiptContents.bytes, Int32(receiptContents.length))
    contents = d2i_PKCS7_bio(receiptBIO, nil)

    //parsing
    var currentIndex    = UnsafePointer<UInt8>()
    var endIndex        = UnsafePointer<UInt8>()

    let octets      = pkcs7_d_data(pkcs7_d_sign(self.contents).memory.contents)

    var ptr = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(octets.memory.data)
    let end = ptr.advancedBy(Int(octets.memory.length))
    println(ptr.memory) //always 49 ???
    println(end.memory) //always 0 ???
    println(octets.memory.length)
```

I tried parsing the NSData myself, but well, what is the type of the binaire data?

```
    receiptContents = NSData(contentsOfURL: receiptLocation)!

    //get bytes
    let count = receiptContents.length / sizeof(UInt8)
    var bytes = [UInt8](count: count, repeatedValue: 0)
    receiptContents.getBytes(&bytes, length:count * sizeof(UInt8))

    //parsing
    for index in 0...5
    {
        let value = Int(bytes[index])
        println(value)
    }
```

I get this output: 
48
130
21
57
6
9

but if understand the ASN.1 format correctly, it's supposed to start with a value of 17 (set), then 3 bytes for the length (Int24?), then a value of 16 (first sequence), sequence length (1 byte), sequence type (1 byte), sequence payload, (repeat).

Other types like Int32, Int16 makes even less sense to me.

Not sure how to proceed here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the outset, I suppose I should disclaim this by saying I'm not very familiar with many of the underlying technologies (Swift, OpenSSL, the Biometrics standards that I think you're working with).

That said, you're probably running afoul of BER's tagging rules. [The Wiki article on X.690](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Encoding_Rules#Identifier_octets) has some introductory comments about how BER tags are constructed, but really you'll want to consult [Annex A of X.690](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.690-200811-I/en) for an example encoding and [X.680 §8](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.680-200811-I/en) for information about tagging.

A `SET` type can appear in several different forms; but in your case `49 = 0x31 = 0b00110001 = UNIVERSAL 17` (`SET`, constructed). Other forms may occur, but this is the only one that's explicitly identified as a `SET` from the tag itself: the specification may use a different tag for a `SET` type.

Comment: decimal 49 is hexadecimal 31 is binary 110001 is an internal ans.1 type?
Why did they do that? Decimals weren't good enough? (sorry, getting a bit frustrated with this)

Comment: @user965972 – (Hopefully) succinctly, ASN.1 has four tagging environments: universal, application, context, and private. The tag type is denoted in the first two bits of the identifier octet(s). Following the tag type is a flag denoting whether the type is primitive (a simple value) or constructed (whether it is a tag-length-value triad). Then the actual tag follows. So in this case, universal 17 is written `0b00|1|10001`: the first `00` is UNIVERSAL, the next `1` means that it's constructed, and the tag value is `10001` for 17.